# Is there a way to automatically insert rows that are updated on a linked server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

The local server (SCADA System) uses SQL Server, and the linked server (ERP System) uses Oracle.

The current situation is as follows:

The ERP system has a table on its server to which all batch orders are consistently updated. I have access to that table, but I cannot manipulate / configure anything from the ERP side. Any configuration / querying must be done on the local server.

I tried querying rows directly from the ERP table, but for some reason that causes a ~30s delay. I then created a local table and inserted all rows from the ERP table, to see if there still would be a delay if I'm querying from the new local table. No delays there. So I figured if I could keep the local table updated as with the ERP table, I just need to use the local table.

So my question is, without the ability to configure / manipulate the ERP side, is there a way to insert all new rows that are updated on the ERP table to our local table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically DBAs for ERP systems don't like to change the main ERP model schema because it creates more objects to deal with during application upgrades - vanilla application upgrades are usually preferred.

What they do sometimes tolerate is to create triggers on the ERP table into another table (your design) inside another Oracle schema which you can manipulate at will.

From this table, you can decide to pull the data into MSSQL through your linked server setting flags as you go or deleting old data so your data fetch is minimized for each call. Typically calling a stored procedure in the new Oracle Schema to perform table updates or deletions seems to work better because linked servers are very slow when pulling data over to the MSSQL side to work on them.

Another alternative (which is much faster than using a linkedServer) is to use a Windows service or a scheduled script(ex VBS) on a windows server to talk to both Oracle and MSSQL to achieve the same objective. This could be done on the original table directly or in the new one.
You would have figure out your polling intervals depending on your near-to-realtime requirements.

Comment: The problem is I cannot manipulate the Oracle side. Is it possible to pull the data to MSSQL side as soon as there is an update in the Oracle side(as if a trigger would), without manipulating the Oracle side?

Comment: Yes of course it is possible but linked servers are very slow.
As you've probably observed, loading from the main schema in linked server is very slow because the main ERP schema has too many objects and data. To maximize performance you may need the data in a place with fewer objects.

In any case, this means a sql agent job (using linked server) or another process wakes up every x seconds/minutes, compares what it last downloaded to what the table has and fetches new data. Perhaps the 30 seconds won't matter as much if realtime isn't as important.

Comment: Would it still be slow if I used table view through linked server? What about table synchronization?

Comment: From a database perspective, I assume you mean a view on the MSSQL side. A materialized view could be done on the oracle side but you have no access there.
A TableView sounds something used in another programming interface outside both ORACLE and MSSQL. Just like a recordset exists in VBA.
I would say to try whatever ideas come to you because that's how you will understand things at the appropriate detail. You may be able to improve your speed based on certain decisions you make on what you pull over.

Comment: As for the table synchronization, sometimes ERP systems use a change tracking tool (like GoldenGate) to track changes which are needed for slowly changing dimensions in a data warehouse.
If your ERP system has such a tool perhaps you could use it but I doubt it will be up to date the way you want it.
A trigger is one way to enable table synchronization but if the source can't push based on an event (row insert/change/delete) then the target has to poll and pull like you plan to do

Comment: Lastly I read somewhere that some of the performance issues with linked servers have been linked to permission issues such the ID running the job not having these roles on the server: sysadmin, db_owner, db_ddladmin. So see if having those rights help somewhat. These are elevated roles which many DBAs would never give an ID but try it to see if speed improves.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I've yet to adapt any of the changes you've mentioned, but it's been great help. Thank you again.

Comment: No worries. Glad to be of service. Post implementation, leave some feedback about what worked if you get the chance.